# Unable to translate "s" letter in tag synonym/merge tool

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, localization

There's a tool available to moderators to synonymize/merge tags.

In case when some tag already has a master tag that tag contains a letter `s` instead of number of questions with that tag:

> [image]

It looks like this `s` means "synonym" or something similar. It is not possible to translate that symbol for non-English sites.

Comment: Generally, is there any sense to have the slave synonym tag in that list?